# Android Studio: What to download in API level 23 and 22

Tags: android

Do I need to download everything (within API 23 and 22) or just a few things. I just want to develop a simple app for Phone/Tablet.
Thank you!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8I6c.jpg]

Comment: I would just dl the latest one for now and dl the rest as you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Documentation - must have
- SDK Platform - of course
- Samples - code samples, not required
- System Images - system images for each platform (for Android emulator). Install one for debugging. In future, it's a good practice to test your app on every platform.
- Google APIs - for Google Play services (like Google+, Games etc), install if you need.
- Sources - SDK source code, download if you want.